# Can't run psql on command line... having installed PostgreSQL.app on macOS Mojave

Tags: postgresql, macos, psql

Error message I get after running in Term2 is...

```
➜  ~ psql
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[1]    12990 abort      psql
```

However psql does show in the standard bin path...

```
➜  ~ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
➜  ~
```

Others described a similar error from Readline but my error only mentions "libpq.5.dylib".

I think it should run OK since it does run from the menu provided by postgres.app...

I am stumped.

Any advice or assistance would be much appreciated : ) ...oh I am using MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave.

Kind regards, Nodrog.

Comment: The `psql` shipped with Postgres.app is not in `/usr/local/bin`. Try opening `psql ` by clicking on the elephant in the menu bar

Comment: Hi richyen, thanks for the suggestion. I can do that yes, however, I am watching tutorial that suggests that psql can run directly from the terminal. See https://youtu.be/qw--VYLpxG4?t=1385      He shows that it doesn't work initially but does work if you use his setup and instructions. I followed his directions (I thought) but did not succeed sadly.

Comment: OK, found the answer after thinking about what richyen said.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I was having with psql is that after installing Postgres.app, the psql supplied inside it was not included in the $PATH variable which I loaded from the file "/etc/paths". I tried first to add the path to psql inside the Postgres.app folder (this can be seen in the header when you open a database from the "elephant in the menu bar" mentioned by richyen). The path to add to this file looks something like...

/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/

In my case, I had two other apps that used psql with other unused implementations  that triggered before my entry on the last line in my "/etc/paths" file.

By moving the above entry to the top of the "/etc/paths" file, I was able to get psql to trigger first (and therefore correctly) just like selecting from the "elephant in the menu bar".

Thanks to richyen for taking the trouble to respond to my question. : D

Kind regards, Nodrog.